# Could dragons be cold-blooded?

Tags: science-fiction, dragons, ice

One of my ideas is a dragon that breathes ice, through liquid CO2, stored in special glands and released through pressure, and cooling. It would gain this large amount of required CO2 from eating chalk and natural metabolism. Would it have to be cold-blooded to maintain its cold temperature? Or would it being warm-blooded affect it? It is a large predator, and it could be somewhere in between, similar to dinosaurs. Would it be able to be cold-blooded, especially if it lives in a freezing environment?

Comment: You know how a refrigeration system works right? to get or keep something cold inside it means you're pumping a lot of heat out of it into the surrounding tissues, chances are good your dragons are going to need some way to keep the rest of their body cooler so they don't overheat, big ears or a sail fin like some dinosaurs to act as a thermal dump they can pump warmer blood through to radiate away the excess heat, at a guess (of the knee jerk variety) they'll need a high metabolism of some sort, because they'll be burning energy to keep that organ cold enough to hold liquid CO2.

Comment: cold blooded means it cannot regulate its body temperature internally and must seek out a heat source usually the Sun and in your particular case those flaming stones fired from the trebuchets...

Comment: There's a creature called a bombardier beetle. It does something similar to shoot hot water.

Comment: To liquify the CO₂ you'd need to increase the pressure (Gay-Lussac's law). This would lead to an increase in temperature (ΔT) equivalent to the ΔT reduction in temperature achieved. You're not reducing temperature, you're _moving_ it. You can't obliterate energy. Our dragon would be extremely hot on the outsides! Also, you don't need to replenish CO₂ unless it leaks; you've described a refrigerant - you don't replace the refrigerant gas in your fridge right? It's a closed loop. [NB. Plus CO₂ makes an appalling refrigerant; because it sublimates (turns into a solid with no liquid stage)].

Comment: @David I believe the bombardier beetle holds two chemicals seperate until needed then brings them together to fire (and a chemical reaction causes them to get hot). It isn't constantly holding them hot (or cold)

Comment: @Rab Freon might be a bit hard for an organic to come by in easily replaceable quantities for something that's spewing it out as a 'breath attack' regularly (for an organic system in an earth like environment), how about Nitrogen instead? .. a modified swim bladder type organ (or increasingly robust series of them) for the pressurization perhaps :)

Comment: Warm blooded and cold blooded are misleading terms that don't actually reflect the reality of how organisms regulate heat. What are generally considered "cold blooded" are ectotherms, that require external heat sources, and what are generally considered "warm blooded" are endotherms, which produce their own heat, but both tend to have a body temperature far higher than the ice you're describing. In fact, ectotherms that get too cold will often die more readily than endotherms, since they can't produce their own heat.

Comment: Of course they could. Why not?

Aren't ice dragons a basic part of D&D, for instance?

If your built world can contain magical creatures, why are you even thinking about 'realistic' constraints?

Quite separately, how is this 'science fiction' rather than 'fantasy'?

Comment: Recall that dry ice, when exposed to the atmosphere, produces an awful lot of fog. But in order to have any real effect outside the body, you would need a LOT of dry ice. What matters is the amount of BTU the dry ice will take out of the atmosphere as it warms up. It might cause very localized frost but it would take gallons of it to  cool an entire human down by even a few degrees. Just a breath is not going to turn someone into a popsicle.

Comment: But the amount of energy that is required to power your internal refrigeration circuit is going to constantly produce so much heat as to make the question moot.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin the tag is science fiction and OP doesn't mention magic, looks like he's looking for non magical solutions for something he wants in his world, a sci fi creature he calls a dragon rather than a fantasy dragon.

Comment: The @RichardTingle comment gives an alternate method of storing a "cold" spray.  It stores separate chemicals that, when combined, create an endothermic reaction that pulls a significant amount of heat from the target.

Comment: @Pelinore The Question is about dragons. How could any tag ever separate dragons from at least one of fantasy and magic?

OP might be trying to make excuses and how d'you this could go further?

Take a look at Anne McCaffrey's Dragonworld, often classed as sci-fi. Beautifully written, calling on various sciences and ultimately, fantasy.

Can you say what difference you see between a sci fi creature he calls a dragon and a fantasy dragon?

Don't you think that's one of the more obvious reasons why so much work is lumped into the one category of 'fantasy and sci-fi'?

Comment: I'm sorry @RobbieGoodwin but try not to be too dim, if you have a big lizard it doesn't need any magic, if you have a big winged lizard that flies but isn't any larger than the largest creatures ever known to have flown it still doesn't need any magic, if it also has a 'breath weapon' grounded in scientific plausibility magic still isn't needed, if you choose to call it a dragon instead of something else it still doesn't need magic, such a thing is perfectly reasonable in any relatively hard sci fi story, you don't have to be writing swords and sorcery to use the word dragon > now add the tag.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin *"fantasy and sci-fi'"* you do realise we have separate tags for [fantasy] and [science-fiction] right? there's a reason for that, it's because they are not the same thing, the science fiction tag does *not* mean 'fantasy ***and*** sci fi', maybe you should read the two tags descriptions.

Comment: @Pelinore  Will you donate some spare spleen as stock to a dragon-bile factory? Either way I'm sorry to have used 'fantasy and sci-fi' in the ordinary sense. 

I gave you air quotes to light the way but I didn't guess you could be too dim to see that, or how many other mis-applied tags this Community has. Right?

You do realise if you call it a dragon, everyone here is entitled - maybe expected - to give 'dragon' its normal face value, right?

It’s good you're coming to see big lizards don’t need to be called dragons but here, Scout Paige chose to dub the critter a dragon.

Comment: @Pelinore  Sorry you don’t realise that no, a big lizard can’t fly… particularly not if it’s anything like the largest creatures ever known to have flown. 

Pterodactyls, pterosaurs and the like aren’t ‘big lizards’. Their anatomy is so different, it's almost literally 'unearthly.'

Sorry you don’t realise a 'breath weapon' can’t be grounded in scientific plausibility, however soft your grasp of science. Ice, fire or halitosis, you can claim a ‘breath weapon’ is ‘perfectly reasonable’ after explaining at least the basic anatomy and physiology. Until then, you’re flailing about in fantasy.

Comment: @Pelinore  What in any world could you mean by ’ > now add the tag’?

Comment: Scout Paige  Sorry, and you did choose to slap a science-fiction tag on a fantasy concept

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin How about you look at the tag, the tag does not support the idea he's looking for a fantasy answer it supports the idea h's looking for a sci fi answer, now add that [to the points I already raised], I thought the untyped bit would be self evident to anyone so wouldn't need typing.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin *"you did choose to slap a science-fiction tag on a fantasy concept"* no he didn't, neither the word dragon nor the concept of a dragon is exclusively a fantasy thing as I've more than adequately demonstrated already, and as those two tags themselves should make clear by their descriptions, it can also be a sci fi thing and done right even a very hard [science fiction] / [science based] thing, it might even be (at an extreme stretch) a [hard science] thing if you work at making it so enough.

Comment: @Pelinore Nuh, nuh, nu, nu, nuh… Yes, he did; yes they are; no, you've tried but inadequately, and so consistently failed. Look how confused you seem even with that last 'it can also be a sci fi thing and (etc)…'

I'm not distorting the language to suit your ideas about science or tags, and I'm sure you feel almost the same, backwards so please, stop wasting your time on me and talk to poor Scout Paige.

Comment: @Pelinore  Please stop insulting everyone's intelligence, including your own. You do know the komodo is special, named directly and solely from the fact that yes, it looks a lot like a fantasy 'dragon'. There's little hope but you might find solace at (paigntonzoo.org.uk/news/paignton-zoos-fire-breathing-dragon/) which seems to have developed the very bile-processor you needed!

Even through blinkers, how is it not obvious Scout Paige chose not to make up a name like frigignispiritus because 'dragon' was needed to conjure up all its legendary associations?

Why not take yourself to Chat?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "You do know the komodo is special, named directly and solely from the fact that yes, it looks a lot like a fantasy 'dragon'" no it doesn't it just looks like a big lizard, but passing on that > you do realise you have just argued against yourself right, if you can name something a dragon that's not a fantasy thing then calling something a dragon doesn't make it a fantasy thing, do you even hear yourself, seems not, you've shot your argument in the foot with your own mouth.

Comment: @Pelinore  Your arguments do seem to be worthy of you and why can you not restrict yourself to helping Scout Paige?

Comment: @Pelinore  Please? Just restrict yourself to helping Scout Paige.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Warm and cold blooded are colloquial terms that really refer to thermo-regulation vs no thermo-regulation. Nothing inherent about warm or cold, just that in real life all examples are thermo-regulating to a warm temperature. There are no examples of organisms in the real world that are refrigerators. Not thermo-regulating in a cold environment implies activity levels that are dependent on temeprature though. Most notably, lack of activity when it is cold, although fish can be active in cold water.

That said, technically liquid CO2 doesn't really line up with a dragon that lives in Earthly freezing temperatures since liquid CO2 is so cold that Earthly freezing temperatures would be considered warm.

Not really a problem though. That just means that your dragon's gland really is a refrigerator: Using energy to thermoregulate the gland by moving heat out of it and dumping it to the surrounding "warmer" temperature. And in that sense, the colder the ambient temperature, the easier it would be. This probably means the rest of your dragon is actually quite warm as it consumes energy to maintain the refrigeration moves the heat from the gland into the rest of its body, which is just as well so it isn't always just lazing around from lack of metabolism.

Comment: So to clarify, it would be better for it to be warm-blooded than cold-blooded?

Comment: @ScoutPaige Yes, you need thermo-regulation since CO2 is significantly colder than the ambient will ever be.

Comment: Liquid CO2 is not necessarily terribly cold, it just has to be at least moderately high pressure. Below 5.1 atmospheres, there is literally no temperature at which CO2 is liquid.

Comment: We thermo-regulate to cool down too using sweat.  "Warm" is just a relative term anyway

Comment: @Cullub I guess sweating is part of homeostatis

Comment: @ScoutPaige, a dragon is likely to be a [gigantotherm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigantothermy): so large that the temperature of its environment has only a minor effect on its body temperature.

Comment: Your problem is going to be how to prevent the dragon from turning itself into a popsicle. For that, the dragon will HAVE to produce internal body heat to warm itself up, even if that 'warming itself up' is to just above freezing. So yes your dragon HAS to be 'warm blooded' in the sense that it generates internal heat for the purposes of maintaining a certain body temperature.

Answer (score 8):

Your question essentially appears to be "is it easier to keep something cold when you're not surrounding it in a substance that produces heat", which: yes. As to whether or not something can be cold-blooded (ie, not producing much heat through its own metabolic processes) while living in a cold environment, and that is certainly possible as long as its basic chemistry is sufficiently different. Cold blooded [icefish have a variety of adaptations](https://cos.northeastern.edu/news/icefish-have-antifreeze-in-their-blood-anemia-and-osteoporosis-and-they-feel-just-fine/) to permit functioning in extreme cold:

> ...antifreeze running through its opalescent white blood... [the] lack of red blood cells means icefish blood is particularly thin, making it easier to circulate in the cold...researchers also found that fish had an excess of genes responsible for creating proteins to keep it from freezing as it ingests ice crystals from the surrounding water

This is about as far as real world animals can get, and anything capable of "breathing ice" will need basic cellular chemistry that deviates drastically from anything on earth. Like, different basic building blocks than the stuff shared by everything from humans and dinosaurs all the way through mushrooms and deep sea vent tube worms and e. coli bacteria. Which is fine; you're making your own world, after all.

What will be trickier is that liquid CO2, which we'll grant your unearthly metabolism is able to create, is a far cry from "breathing ice". Assuming a vaguely earth-like environment, CO2 can only be liquid under fairly high pressure (5.2 atmospheres), so even if your icy dragon has pressure tank bladders internally, the second it starts to breathe it you no longer have liquid CO2. You have a rapidly expanding gas, which may or may not be useful as a weapon but is absolutely a tremendously effective method of propulsion, that unfortunately is pushing the head of your dragon in a direction it probably doesn't want to go. At snout-petting range this sudden expansion of very cold gas would be quite unpleasant and potentially fatal, assuming a large dragon and a good flow rate. At more than a few meters of range, it's a chilly breeze that will refresh the onlookers being entertained by watching a dragon being launched backwards by its own invisible rocket belching. Expanding gases aren't like streams of liquid, and will spread out very quickly in every direction. To have any force at range would require a force at point of origin that is literally the strength of a bomb, since bombs are definitionally things that generate very rapidly expanding gases. Do recall that the point of origin for this expanding gas is inside the throat and skull of your dragon, so some caution is advised.

Even liquid nitrogen isn't really much like breathing ice. I've recreationally splashed myself and friends with liquid nitrogen. As with many activities undertaken by adolescent idiots, it's absolutely fine right up until it very, very much is not, so please do not try this at home. But due to a fun phenomenon known as the [Leidenfrost effect](https://demos.smu.ca/demos/thermo/9-leidenfrost-effect), a brief dousing of liquid nitrogen will actually result in less cooling than being splashed with the same amount of ice water.

If you truly want a cold-based breath weapon, you need to get into extremely exotic chemistry like supposing some sort of violently endothermic chemical reaction, spraying two separate chemicals that when they combine absorb a great deal of heat from their environment. There are real-world chemicals that do this on a small scale, such as [ammonium chloride and barium hydroxide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQkJI-Nq3Os). But for complicated reasons that go deeper into thermodynamics than I'm comfortable swimming, we don't really expect to see actual chemicals that do this in a dramatic way. So you'll need some unobtanium if you want to stay in a supposedly scientific frame.

A final alternative for a cold-based breath weapon is exotic physics: some means of manipulating energy fields in a way that reduces the vibration of atoms within the area of effect. In our universe, that reduction the energy of one system means the energy has to go somewhere else, so it could be a way that the dragons "eat" the heat from their targets to keep themselves warm, assuming that's something they want. But this kind of field manipulation is so deep into Star Trek technobabble that it might as well be magic.

Sadly, absolutely none of these will produce the icy blast we're used to seeing in comics. If you want that solid blast of ice, your dragon has to vomit every single ounce of that up as water first. And since unlike gases, water doesn't compress, that means your dragon is a giant waddling sloshing reptilian water balloon that can presumably immobilize its prey through laughter and doesn't need all the fancy science to freeze them as well.